# Sending option to database from spark jdbc connection

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, db2

I'm trying to write a large dataframe to a db2 database but I'm running into logs on the server getting too large with my session. How can I send a `+c` flag which is used with insert commands from spark to db2 so that it bypasses the logging all together? Is there a way to submit database commands somehow from spark? I can issue a command from a db library like scalike but not sure how to use both in tandem.

Answer (score 0):

A good example of an X-Y problem.

`+c` seems to be referring to an argument of the Db2 command line processor (CLP) that turns off autocommit.

Firstly, since you're running Spark, the CLP is nowhere in the picture.

Secondly, disabling autocommit, if you were able to do so, could only worsen your problem, which seems to be you running out of log space: with less frequent commits you would need more log space, not less.

Thirdly, you cannot possibly "bypass the logging all together" when using an SQL interface, such as JDBC (used by Spark) or ODBC.

The best you can do in this situation is to speak with the DBA responsible for the database in question to find out ways to tune the query generated by Spark or ask for an increased log space.